# How to show Android Notifications on screen as well as status bar icon?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I feel like this should be trivial but I can't seem to make a notification show up on the phone's screen - it only shows up in the status bar at the top.

For an example of what I want to do, here's how Facebook Messenger shows up on the screen when you receive a message.

[image: Facebook on-screen notification]

Whenever I send a notification, all it does is show the little icon in the status bar - even if I set the priority to PRIORITY_MAX. Is there another setting I need to do to make it show on screen instead of just status bar?

The Notification display code:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, nextId++, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
       .setContentTitle(title)
       .setContentText(description)
       .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification)
       .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
       .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
       .setAutoCancel(true)
       .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    builder.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange_500))
           .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
}

Notification notification = builder.build();
notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

Comment: A heads-up notification like that should arise through using high priority with your `NotificationCompat.Builder`. See: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/Lollipop

Comment: Ah, there it is. Weird that you'd need to use `NotificationCompat.Builder` to do that. If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All things considered, it's a *really* good idea to use `NotificationCompat.Builder` over `Notification.Builder`, let alone creating a `Notification` manually. It gives you nice backwards compatibility with graceful degradation (all the way back to API Level 4, otherwise known as "gadzooks, that's old"). AFAIK, it's the only way to get some of the Android Wear stuff going, when used in concert with `NotificationManagerCompat`. And, in this case, it seems to be happier with the newer Android 5.0+ features.

In this case, `setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)` on a `NotificationCompat.Builder`, used with `NotificationManagerCompat`, will give you the heads-up notification on Android 5.0+.

Comment: i use this approch on android 7 and 10 none of them have shown notification pop up

Answer (score 10):

Another point, make sure the 'importance' of the [notification channel](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) you have set up for your notification is set to `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH`.

This configures how visually intrusive notifications posted to this channel are and 'high' will allow it to peek. If you have this set to `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` then it won't!

*Bear in mind when configuring a notification channel, once the code has ran on your device, you won't be able to alter this again. So if you need to change the importance **you will need to uninstall the app and then re-run** and you should see the notification on your screen!*

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about reinstalling the app.